# Need a help to parse json file/string without Key

Tags: java, json, android-json

```
{"5303b93":["F2424F",40.53,22.97,0,0,0,"0000","T-LGTS2","A139","-",1421675730,"","","",1,0,"UPDATE-YOUR-FR24-APP",0],  
 "5323c35":["F2424F",50.10,14.26,51,0,0,"2104","T-LKPR27","A139","",1421675730,"","","",1,0,"UPDATE-YOUR-FR24-APP",0]}
```

Comment: @frasnian what he is asking is how to parse JSON without the key in the key value pairs in the object

Comment: Pardon me @frasnian as I am new to JSON.
I am trying to parse JSON string like this-
    {"5303b93":["F2424F",40.53,22.97,0,0,0,"0000","T-LGTS2","K139","-",1421675730,"","","",1,0,"UPDATE-YOUR-APP",0],
"5323c35":["F2424F",50.10,14.26,51,0,0,"2104","T-LKPR27","AK39","",1421675730,"","","",1,0,"UPDATE-YOUR-APP",0]}

Comment: Thanks @Rafael for understanding the question. I tried below code from stackoverflow but dnt know how to proceed-
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response_str);
JSONArray arrayJson = jsonObj.getJSONArray("DONT_KNOW_WAT_TO KEEP HERE");

for (int i = 0; i < arrayJson.length(); i++) {
    String values= arrayJson.getString(i);
   
}

Comment: Are you trying to iterate all the arrays but ignoring the keys?

Comment: @ikettu: yes I am doing that as i dnt have key. but my node is changing everytime as first its "5303b93" then "5323c35" and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(str); 
JSONArray arrayJson = jsonObj.getJSONArray("5303b93");
for (int i = 0; i < arrayJson.length(); i++) { 
  String values= arrayJson.getString(i); 
}
```

Since isnt "`5303b93`" the key for first array?

If you want to iterate all the arrays ignoring the keys

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(str); 
Iterator it = jsonObj.keys();
while (it.hasNext()) {
  JSONArray arrayJson = jsonObj.getJSONArray((String)it.next());
  for (int i = 0; i < arrayJson.length(); i++) { 
    String values= arrayJson.getString(i); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this what you needed, or do you need further help?

Answer (score 0):

try this

**Strings.xml**

```
<string name="json_data">{"5303b93":["F2424F",40.53,22.97,0,0,0,"0000","T-LGTS2","A139","-",1421675730,"","","",1,0,"UPDATE-YOUR-FR24-APP",0], "5323c35":["F2424F",50.10,14.26,51,0,0,"2104","T-LKPR27","A139","",1421675730,"","","",1,0,"UPDATE-YOUR-FR24-APP",0]}</string>
```

**JAVA Code :**

```
JSONObject jsonObj = null;
    try {
        jsonObj = new JSONObject(getString(R.string.json_data));
        JSONArray jsonArray1 = jsonObj.getJSONArray("5303b93");
        JSONArray jsonArray2 = jsonObj.getJSONArray("5323c35");
        for(int i= 0 ; i<jsonArray1.length(); i++){
            if(jsonArray1.getString(i) != null){
                String tempStr = jsonArray1.getString(i);
                if(tempStr != null)
                    Log.i("===First Array==="+i, "==="+tempStr+"===");
            }
        }
        for(int i= 0 ; i<jsonArray2.length(); i++){
            if(jsonArray2.getString(i) != null){
                String tempStr = jsonArray2.getString(i);
                if(tempStr != null)
                    Log.i("===Second Array==="+i, "==="+tempStr+"===");
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: What is R in above code.
Also I cnt use 
JSONArray jsonArray1 = jsonObj.getJSONArray("5303b93");
        JSONArray jsonArray2 = jsonObj.getJSONArray("5323c35"); bcz 5303b93,5323c35 are not fixed.It will keep on changing everytime.

Comment: the code JSONArray jsonArray1 = jsonObj.getJSONArray("5303b93");  is throwing compilation error "The method getJSONArray(String) is undefined for the type JSONObject"

Comment: R indicates Resources in java. In the above code  response getting from srtings.xml. If key values keep changing, get key and iterate array

Comment: Ohh now i figure out u given code in reference to android but i am making use in my java standalone application